# CSS image stuck at the bottom

Tags: css

I have this image that I'm trying to position to a certain spot, but no matter what I try the image stays a the bottom. I've been able to center the image horizontally but now I want to manipulate it vertically and get it to the top or near the top area. It baffles me how margin isn't working; how would I go by doing it?

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    height: 100vh; 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#e66465, #9198e5);
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.signup-forms{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    max-width: 350px;
    margin: 5% auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0 #3d3d3d6e;
    padding: 20px 5px;
}

.signup-forms h3{
    color: #EB4D8A;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.signup-forms p{
    color: #C3BFDA;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: small;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.signup-input{
    outline: none;
    width: 75%;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C3BFDA;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 15px;
}

.signup-input::placeholder{
    color: #C3BFDA;
}

.signup-btn{
    background-color: #fc4186;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.signup-btnTwitter{
    background-color: #54ACF0;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.logo-img{
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 100%;
}
```

The image I'm trying to manipulate is `.logo-img`

Comment: we need html code to show what is wrong with your css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't know much since there's not html code, but you can do :

```
`margin-top : -100px` //or how many pixels you like
```

or you can use the :top or bottom

Example:

```
top: 20%
```

or

```
bottom : 20%
```

or you can :

```
position: absolute;
z-index : 1;
```

Comment: Yes, sorry for not putting up the HTML, but this solved the problem so thanks!